# This CSS code break my borders

Tags: html, css, overlay, border

I inserted this code to build a thumb gallery but it messed up my left and right border of my wrapper (it disappear).  You can see it here http://blog.howtodjango.com/temp/template/

below is the code that causes it.

```
.gallery li {
display: inline;
list-style: none;
width: 126px;
min-height: 175px;
float: left;
margin: 15px 15px 1px 15px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set overflow:auto and remove the left padding on #main-content

```
#main-content {
background: none;
overflow: auto;
padding-top: 5px;
```

}

That works for me.

Comment: No problem. Can you mark this as best answer? I'm new to the site and don't have many answers yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
#main-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 250px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

If you wanna figure out why, read [this](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)

Comment: if he does, the page layout is broken

Comment: Well, it causes by other problem. His question is "my left and right border of my wrapper (it disappear)". My answer tells him why it disappear. Besides, I don't know what kinda layout he wants, I can't make further suggestion. I think use a wrong way to fix a problem doesn't make it become a correct solution. #page-wrap is the top wrapper, your suggestion will cause other issue in the future if he need scroll bar somewhere.

Comment: At that time, he will come back and ask another question like where the hell is my scroll bar. lol

Comment: loool xDD also true.. stack rulez though :D he'll learn much hangin here all day long :D

Comment: Yea I'm pretty sure I'll need my scroll bar. I thought that code looks suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

this is related to floating

elements to left, add this css:

```
#page-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If he does this, his #main-content is useless

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove an extra `div` tag that exists in your code. Delete one of them at the end and see if this works. Or you could be missing an open tag. Since you did not post your code I cannot figure this out.